# Django: Passing multiple json objects from view

Tags: django

View:

```
def some_view(request,number):
    car=Car.objects.get(id=number)
    person=Person.objects.get(name=car.owner)
    car_json=serializers.serialize("json",[car])
    car_json = car_json.strip("[]")
    person_json=serializers.serialize("json",[person])
    person_json = person_json.strip("[]")
    return HttpResponse(car_json, mimetype="application/json")
```

I am able to pass single json object over to the template. But how do I need to pass both car_json and person_json?

Answer (score 1):

You could **combine them into one object and then send them**, because you can send only a single dict as response:

e.g.

```
obj = {
   'car': serializers.serialize('json', [Car.objects.get(id=number)]).strip("[]"),
   'person': serializers.serialize('json', [Person.objects.get(name=car.owner)]).strip("[]")
}

obj_json = json.dumps(obj)
```

You can also use `Car.objects.filter(id=number)` and `Person.objects.filter(name=car.owner)`.. Just a little optimization

Comment: sorry, this did not work for me. Don't we need to put car_json and person_json in the dict?

Comment: Ohh,, yeah,, You should try that,, just replace above objects with car_jason and person_json

Comment: Being a dict object, serializer on obj is causing issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
all_objects = list(Restaurant.objects.all()) + list(Place.objects.all())
data = serializers.serialize('json', all_objects)
```

More: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/

Comment: in my case, car and person are single list objects